# JavaScript how to make backspace work in my keyCode text prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a way to type anywhere by intercepting the `keydown` event instead of using a text box for a project. I'm having trouble finding out how to implement the backspace. This is a shortened version of my code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    typed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    display += typed;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = letterContainer;
});
```

I was trying to use the .replace function like this...

```
if (event.keyCode == 8) {
    display.replace(typed,'');
}
```

...and put it at the beginning, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: So whe keydown acts as a backspace?

Comment: not `display.replace()` - try `display.slice(0,-1)` that will remove the last letter from the string (acting as an array of chars)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting there. How are you emptying the text in the input tag?

```
if (event.keyCode == 8) {
    display.replace(typed,'');
    // ^ This does not change the value of the <input>
}
```

I'd suggest something like:

```
function isDeleteKeyCode(event) {
    return event && event.keyCode === 8;
}

function resetValue(element) {
    element.value = '';
}

$('#input-id').keydown(function(event) {
    if (isDeleteKeyCode(event)) {
        resetValue(event.target);
    }

    // ^ This can be simplified as: isDeleteKeyCode(event) && resetValue(event.target)
});
```

That would add a keydown listener to an input tag with `id="input-id"`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pp16tru7/

Answer (score 0):

```
var display = '';
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var typed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    // if backspace, get text without the last character, else add character to display
    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        display = display.substr(0, display.length - 1);
    } else {
        display += typed;
    }
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = display;
});
```